# How to read a file from installed folder c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I'm using Visual Studio and I have a code that uses several files and made an installer for it. Everything works fine if the user installs the program to the directory that is mentioned in the code (`c:\games`).

For example:

```
FILE *myfile;
if ((myfile = fopen("c:\\games\\heretics.txt", "r")) == NULL) { 
    printf("Cannot Open File heretics.txt\n"); return -1; 
}

while ( (fgets(p, 256, myfile)) != NULL ) {
    printf("%s",p);
}
fclose(myfile);
```

It stops working if the user installs it to any other directory. How to make the program read the files from any directory or what could be the solution for this?

Comment: Use relative paths instead of absolute paths.

Comment: I have properly formatted your source code. Stack Overflow users would appreciate it if you did this for future code as well. If your actual source code doesn't look like this, I *strongly* recommend you start doing so. Having inconsistent braces and multiple statements on a line is just setting yourself up for disaster, and is liable to piss off coworkers.

Comment: Thank you for formatting. It looks good in my code, I just got some problems pasting it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a "heretics.txt" file is in directory of your program (or somewhere near in directory tree) you can just write something like:

```
fopen("heretics.txt", "r") // to open file from current directory
fopen("..\\heretics.txt", "r") // to open file from parent directory
// and so on ;)
```

to use relative path instead of absolute path (as mentioned in comment above).

Comment: @MonkeyTruck Nice to hear (or read ;) ). Since this answer helped you, you can accept it as solution by clicking at checkmark next to it. It will give both you and person who answered some reputation and will mark question as solved. It's not required but highly recommended. :-)

Comment: This might appear to work, but it relies on what the working directory is. And the working directory is not guaranteed to be the location of the EXE file.

Comment: It's probably more practical to store data underneath the working directory rather than above. E.g. if you run the program from C:\Programs\Foo then you don't want to store your data in C:\Programs. Also for portability use `/` as path separator. `fopen("data/heretics.txt", "r")`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to read files from the directory that the application's EXE file is in, you will need to determine that directory at run-time. Don't hard-code paths into your source code, or rely on the working directory!

To do that in Windows, you can call the [`GetModuleFileName` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx), which will return the fully-qualified path to the EXE file. Then you need to strip the EXE file name from the path (e.g. using [`PathRemoveFileSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748.aspx)), to give you the directory.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")
```

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH);
PathRemoveFileSpec(szPath);
```

You can then append your file name to the path like so:

```
PathAppend(szPath, TEXT("heretics.txt"));
```

And then you can pass `szPath` as the fully-qualified path to `fopen` or whatever function you're using to open the file.

#### But...

You should consider carefully whether the application's directory is the best place to store these files.

If either the application itself is going to write to the files (e.g., update them with new changes), or if the user might want to edit them, the application's directory is a terrible place. By default, applications get installed into the "Program Files" directory, for which users do not have edit privileges. Same thing with your example, at the root level of the disk.

Instead, you should save the files from one of the "Application Data" folders. You have the following choices:

- `FOLDERID_ProgramData` (a global program data directory available to all users)
- `FOLDERID_LocalAppData` (a per-user program data directory, non-roaming)
- `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData` (a per-user program data directory, roaming)

Those magic names are the `KNOWNFOLDERID` constants that you pass to the [`SHGetKnownFolderPath` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) to retrieve the path to one of these folders. For example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "shell32.lib")
```

```
// Retrieve the path.
PWSTR pszPath;
HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_ProgramData,
                                  0,     // no special options required
                                  NULL,  // no access token required
                                  &pszPath);
                                  
// Copy it into a local string.
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
lstrcpy(szPath, pszPath);

// Free the memory allocated by the SHGetKnownFolderPath function,
// so you don't accidentally leak it!
CoTaskMemFree(pszPath);
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Thank you for your answer. I like the way you put it and will try to investigate it further.